# Archiving Xcode Project for Submission

Tags: ios, xcode, submission, archiving

When trying to archive an Xcode project for submission when setting Archive Build configuration to release, even when Reveal Archive in Organizer is checked, the Archive does not get created in the Organizer. I get the message, build succeeded though. Anybody knows what could be the reason(s)?

Comment: Sounds like everything should work. If the Archive build is successful it will show up in Organizer -> Archives -> <Your Target Name> -> <List of all archived builds>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I missed some steps when I created the Distribution Provisioning Profile. After creating Distribution Provisioning Profile correctly, everything started to act as I wished.

Comment: yeah apple's dev portal leaves a lot to be desired :/